# SelectRadio how to display radio buttons side by side

Tags: visualforce, radio-button

I need to display Redio buttons side by side. like below
[image]

But they are displaying like 
[image]

My VF code so far (I need to render some part of the page based on user selection of Income/Expense/Transfer):

```
<apex:page id="pageNewReservation"  docType="html-5.0"  standardController="Journal__c" extensions="tie" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="true" > 
<html>
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <head>
            <style>
                *{
                }
                body{
                width:35rem;
                padding:0.2rem;
                }

                .radioOpt td, .radioOptinput, .radioOpt label{
                width: 90%; font-size : 20px;     
                display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto;   
                }   
                .radioOpt td:nth-child(1) { font-size:1rem; background-color: green; padding:.8rem 0 .8rem 0; color:white; border-radius:1.5rem; margin: 0 .5rem 0 .5rem; }
                .radioOpt td:nth-child(2) { font-size:1rem; background-color: blue; padding:.8rem 1rem .8rem 1rem; color:white; border-radius:1.5rem; margin: 0 .5rem 0 .5rem;  }
                .radioOpt td:nth-child(3) { font-size:1rem; background-color: red; padding:.8rem 1rem .8rem 1rem; color:white; border-radius:1.5rem; margin: 0 .5rem 0 .5rem;  }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:outputPanel > 
                        <table border="" class="WizardTable radioOpt" style="width:90%;" >     
                            <tr>
                                <td  style="width:90%;">
                                    <!--  <apex:selectList id="picklistToChangeVF" value="{!selectedRT}" size="1" multiselect="false" >

                                    <apex:selectRadio styleClass="radioOpt" value="{!selectedRT}" id="outMailshot_Frequency__c"> 
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="INCOME" itemLabel=" Income  " /> 
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="EXPENSE" itemLabel="Expense" /> 
                                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="TRANSFER" itemLabel="Transfer" />     
                                        <apex:actionSupport reRender="areaForList" event="onchange" action="{!onChangeSelectRadio}" />     
                                    </apex:selectRadio>
                                </td>                                                        
                            </tr>
                        </table> 
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:actionRegion>

            </apex:pageBlock> 
            <apex:pageBlock id="areaForList"> <!-------------- Area which will rerender based on user selection on JOURNAL TYPE -------------->

                <!--  -----------------------------------------------------  Income -------------------------------------- --- -->
                <apex:pageBlock title="Income"  rendered="{!pb1Rendered}" mode="maindetail">
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="blocksection3" layout="block">


                        <div style="width:28rem; background-color:#EBF5FB;">
                            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                                <h3 style="color:blue; margin-bottom:0">Value</h3>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.Value__c}" style="width:27rem;background-color:#EBF5FB; border-color:#3498DB; margin-bottom:1.5rem;" /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                                <h3 style="color:blue; margin-bottom:0">Date*</h3>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.Journal_Date__c}" style="border-radius:2rem; border-color:#D6EAF8;  " />   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        </div>

                        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                                Category  <br/>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >     <c:TypeAheadComponent2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="General_Ledge_Account__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!Journal__c.General_Ledger_Account__c}" style="width:10rem; margin:0; border-radius:1rem;"  /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                Person   <br/>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >    <c:TypeAheadComponent2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="Account" valueField="Id" targetField="{!Journal__c.Account__c}" style="width:10rem; margin:0; border-radius:1rem;"  /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                                Account <br/>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.General_Ledger_Account__c}" style="border-radius:1.5rem; margin-bottom:1rem;" /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                                <!--        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    <c:TypeAheadComponent2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="General_Ledge_Account__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!Journal__c.General_Ledger_Account__c}" style="width:10rem; margin:0; border-radius:1rem;"  />  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><apex:pageBlockSectionItem > <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.Company__c}" style="border-radius:1.5rem; margin-bottom:1rem;" /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >     <c:TypeAheadComponent2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="Company__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!Journal__c.Company__c}" style="width:10rem; margin:0; border-radius:1rem;"  />
                                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:outputPanel>                        

                    <div style="background-color:gray; margin:1rem; padding: 1rem">
                        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

                            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!objItem}" var="item" >
                                <apex:column headerValue="Item" > 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.Product_Inv__c}" /> </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity" >
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.Quantity__c}" />  </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Price/Unit" > 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.Price__c }" /> </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Total" > 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.Price__c }" /> </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageblockTable>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </div>
                </apex:pageBlock> <!-- end of income -->
                <!--  -----------------------------------------------------  Expense -------------------------------------- --- -->
                <apex:pageBlock title="Expense"  rendered="{!pb2Rendered}" mode="maindetail">
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="blocksection3" layout="block">


                        <div style="width:28rem; background-color:#EBF5FB;">
                            Expense text
                            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                                <h3 style="color:blue; margin-bottom:0">Value</h3>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.Value__c}" style="width:27rem;background-color:#EBF5FB; border-color:#3498DB; margin-bottom:1.5rem;" /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                                <h3 style="color:blue; margin-bottom:0">Date*</h3>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.Journal_Date__c}" style="border-radius:2rem; border-color:#D6EAF8;  " />   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        </div>

                        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                                Category  <br/>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >     <c:TypeAheadComponent2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="General_Ledge_Account__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!Journal__c.General_Ledger_Account__c}" style="width:10rem; margin:0; border-radius:1rem;"  /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                Person   <br/>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >    <c:TypeAheadComponent2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="Account" valueField="Id" targetField="{!Journal__c.Account__c}" style="width:10rem; margin:0; border-radius:1rem;"  /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                                Account <br/>
                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.General_Ledger_Account__c}" style="border-radius:1.5rem; margin-bottom:1rem;" /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                                <!--        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    <c:TypeAheadComponent2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="General_Ledge_Account__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!Journal__c.General_Ledger_Account__c}" style="width:10rem; margin:0; border-radius:1rem;"  />  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><apex:pageBlockSectionItem > <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.Company__c}" style="border-radius:1.5rem; margin-bottom:1rem;" /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >     <c:TypeAheadComponent2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="Company__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!Journal__c.Company__c}" style="width:10rem; margin:0; border-radius:1rem;"  />
                                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:outputPanel>                        

                    <div style="background-color:gray; margin:1rem; padding: 1rem">
                        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

                            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!objItem}" var="item" >
                                <apex:column headerValue="Item" > 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.Product_Inv__c}" /> </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity" >
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.Quantity__c}" />  </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Price/Unit" > 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.Price__c }" /> </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Total" > 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!item.Price__c }" /> </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageblockTable>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </div>
                </apex:pageBlock> <!-- Expense -->
                <!--  -----------------------------------------------------  Transfer -------------------------------------- --- -->
                <apex:pageBlock title="Transfer"  rendered="{!pb3Rendered}" mode="maindetail">
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="blocksection3" layout="block">
                        Transfer
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlock>

            </apex:pageBlock> <!-- Radio button --> 
            <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                        Note <br/> 
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > <apex:inputField value="{!Journal__c.Journal_Description__c}" style="border-radius:1.5rem; margin-bottom:1rem;" /> </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                        Receipt Photo <br/>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:inputFile fileName="{!attachment.name}" value="{!attachment.body}" id="file"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:commandButton value="  Cancel  " action="{!cancel}" immediate="true" style=" border-radius:1rem;" />
                <apex:commandButton value="  Save  " action="{!save}" style="background-color: #3498DB; border-radius:1rem; float:right " />
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </body>
    </apex:form>
</html>
```

By removing CSS for radioOpt, the buttons are like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably this is the part that matters:

```
<apex:selectRadio styleClass="radioOpt" value="{!selectedRT}" id="outMailshot_Frequency__c"> 
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="INCOME" itemLabel=" Income  " /> 
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="EXPENSE" itemLabel="Expense" /> 
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="TRANSFER" itemLabel="Transfer" />     
    <apex:actionSupport reRender="areaForList" event="onchange" action="{!onChangeSelectRadio}" />     
</apex:selectRadio>
```

`<apex:selectRadio>` takes a parameter `layout` which can either be:

- `lineDirection` (horizontal)
- `pageDirection` (vertical)

Check out more [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm), but you should get this effect by doing this:

```
<apex:selectRadio layout="lineDirection" styleClass="radioOpt" value="{!selectedRT}" id="outMailshot_Frequency__c">
```

**Edit**

Based on your comments, it'll be a CSS issue. You can either remove the CSS for `radioOpt` to see if you get the same problem, but I have noticed that in your `.radioOpt td:nth-child(1) {` class, the line:

```
padding:.8rem 0 .8rem 0;
```

Is not the same as the padding applied to the other two:

```
padding:.8rem 1rem .8rem 1rem;
```

Comment: I tried that, no luck.

Comment: Seems like 1st selectOption (Income in my case) is behaving like parent for 2nd, 3rd option.

Comment: @tanmoy See my edits.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions. Still, selectOption 2 & 3 are considered as child of selectOption1. Dont know why

Comment: If I withdraw CSS for radioOpt, radioButton are inline, but selectOption 2 & 3are considered as child of selectOption1. Dont know why.
Padding has no visual impact.

Comment: Removing the TABLE html tag solved the issue